# Show that $(a+b)^n ≡ a^n + b^n (mod 2)$ for all $a,b$ and for $n≥1$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruences

Show that $(a+b)^n ≡ a^n + b^n  (mod 2)$  for all $a,b$ and for $n≥1$

What is the solution of this problem?
Thanks for the answers!

Comment: You know arithmetic modulo 2 is just knowing whether a number is odd or even. How does oddness or evenness change under raising a number to the power $n$?

Answer (score 3):

$$(0+0)^n \equiv 0^n \equiv 0 \equiv 0 + 0 \equiv 0^n + 0^n$$
$$(0+1)^n \equiv 1^n \equiv 1 \equiv 0 + 1 \equiv 0^n + 1^n$$
$$(1+0)^n \equiv 1^n \equiv 1 \equiv 1 + 0 \equiv 1^n + 0^n$$
$$(1+1)^n \equiv 0^n \equiv 0 \equiv 1 + 1 \equiv 1^n + 1^n$$

Answer (score 1):

*Lil' Fermat* says for any $a$, $a^2\equiv a\mod 2$. An easy induction shows that, as a consequence, $a^n\equiv a\mod 2$ for all $n\ge 1$. Thus the congruence $(a+b)^n\equiv a^n+b^n\;$ becomes simply
$$a+b\equiv a+b,$$
which I leave as an exercise.